# Как вызываются методы [HttpGet] [HttpPost]?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Код Представления:

```
<td><p><a href="/Home/Buy/@b.Id">Купить</a></p></td>
```

Код контроллера:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Buy(int id)
{
    ViewBag.BookId = id;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public string Buy(Purchase purchase)
{
    purchase.Date = DateTime.Now;
    // добавляем информацию о покупке в базу данных
    db.Purchases.Add(purchase);
    // сохраняем в бд все изменения
    db.SaveChanges();
    return "Спасибо," + purchase.Person + ", за покупку!";
}
```

При нажатии на ссылку каким будет порядок вызова методов? Как будут выполнятся запросы?

Comment: Также, мне кажется, вам надо чуть глубже изучить вопрос. Я имею ввиду, ну вот у вас есть 2 метода, один для гет запроса, другой для пост запроса. Есть ссылка. Как вы думаете, клик по вашей ссылке заставляет браузер выполнить гет или пост запрос? Как вы вообще представляете отправку пост запроса на сервер?

Comment: 2 метода с одинаковым названием. При клике как будут вызваны методы? Параллельно?

Comment: при отправке запроса браузером к серверу, браузер указывает тип запроса. Тип запрос может быть только один. У вас 2 функции, одна будет вызвана при типе проса GET, другая - при типе запроса POST. Один запрос вызовет только одну функцию. Ссылки браузер открывает ГЕТ запросом, потому при клике на ссылку вызовется ГЕТ запрос. Это же основы, почитайте хоть что то по тому, с чем работаете.

Comment: @tym32167 верно, разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что тут думать - вызовется GET метод, потому что переход по ссылке браузерами трактуется как GET.

POST-запрос из браузера возможен, если у вас объявлена форма и метод формы установлен в POST.

```
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit">title</button>
</form>
```

Ну или по-mvc'шному:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Actionname", "Controllername", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit">button title</button>
}
```

Ну и во всяких ajax-конструкциях метод будет зависеть от того, что вы там напишете.

Вам нужно разобраться в том, как происходит поиск нужного action, подходящего под запрос, особенно обратив внимание на активатор action'ов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Браузер отправил GET запрос на некоторый URL, механизм asp.net mvc ищет соответствующий route, который бы подпадал под url. Далее создаётся экземпляр контроллера, а далее ищется наиболее подходящий экшн. Может быть несколько одинаковых action с одинаковым именем. Какой выбрать - определяется атрибутами. В запросе был Get, но на одном из action есть Post (Only) и он отпадает, а второй подходит - он-то и вызовется. До action с POST управление не дойдёт никак, он отпадает на более ранней стадии.

Подробнее:

- [Методы действий и их параметры](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/3.2.php)
- [Фабрика контроллеров и активатор действий](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level4/4_7.php)

Comment: `Ну или по-mvc'шному:` – в MVC Core этот подход уже устаревший, новый подход – дескрипторные вспомогательные классы

Comment: тут 2 метода с одним названием. И get и post будут вызваны. Паралелльно или в каком порядке? Или я вообще в заблуждении и работают запросы иначе?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я в курсе, но вопрос про классический mvc, так что мне пришлось ещё поискать старый код.

Comment: @СысоевГриша Вызовется только GET.

Comment: @AK верно. Спасибо

Comment: Обязательно почитайте про "Активатор действий занимается поиском и вызовом метода действия в классе контроллера." - сразу станет понятно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP и где почитать про этот новый подход? Я вижу только упоминание в гугле в содержании каких-то книг и нигде больше.

Comment: @vitidev, ну я Адама Фримена читаю сейчас: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/139614503/ . Он уже выпустил и по Core 2, но на русском пока не нету

Comment: @vitidev, tag-хелперы: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/10.1.php https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/10.4.php

Comment: @АндрейNOP ясно. Проблема локализации, когда tag helpers переводят как "дескрипторные вспомогательные классы"